# CentOS 7 sssd with AD - getent passwd slow in response

Tags: active-directory, centos7, sssd

CentOS 7 + SSSD + AD

AD user is created through bash script. To confirm the AD user account is created I am using `getent passwd <username>`. It is not returning the user account created in AD immediately, but it is returning the user account after a minute or so when using the same `getent passwd <username>`.

Is there any config parameter to change in `sssd.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, enumerating all users and storing them to the cache (with enumerate=True) is expensive and runs only periodically.

Running getent passwd $username should yield the user immediatelly, though.

Answer (score 0):

Setting:

```
enumerate = true
```

will allow sssd to get all the valid user details and store them but comes at a price if you have a large number of users according to the man page for sssd.conf (Here's a link to it: https://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd.conf). From experience, we have 700+ and it's not a problem.

Also setting:

```
cache_credentials = true
```

should help, but should already be set. Details on same man page.